How to return a number of cells without a dependent in the given sheet?
I work for a large organisation and got a huge excel sheet I have to check.
I have to validate if the calculations are done correctly and if the logic is correct. It is a horrible task considering the excel has something around 3mils of formulas across 43 tabs.
I want to demonstrate that the excel sheet has many problems. I managed to do several things like how many erroneous formulas there are per tab, etc.
There is one FINAL tab that contains the final calculated outputs. I would like to show that there are many cells in the non-FINAL tabs that do not have any dependents - they are either abandoned calculations or abandoned constants. How can I calculate the number of cells without any dependent in a given sheet?
Thanks for any VBA script - I am not searching for some super-simple solution. I can imagine that I cannot do it without VBA scripting...
I thought about selecting some range in the tabs go iteratively cell by cell within the range and test if this -->      [[  Range("T11").Dependents  ]]    returns any addresses.
Is this the only way?

How to select the minimal range that contains all active cells?
could you add any script you have available and are allowed to share?


You are on the right track using Dependents (or Precedents, if you are interested in that). You can easily write a routine around that that dumps all dependent cells for a Range or Worksheet - or that dumps all cells that have no such dependents.
The following routine gives you an idea how it could look like. It expects three parameters:

The first (rangeOrWs) defines the range you want to analyze. It must be a Range or a Worksheet
The second defines if you want to list dependent or precedent cells
The thirds defines if you want to list all dependencies or if you want to list cells that have no dependencies.

The code assumes that the workbook where it lives contains sheets named "Dependents" resp. "Precedents"
Sub listDependencies(rangeOrWs, _
                     Optional listDependents As Boolean = True, _
                     Optional listOrphans As Boolean = False)

    Dim r As Range
    If TypeName(rangeOrWs) = "Range" Then
        Set r = rangeOrWs
    ElseIf TypeName(rangeOrWs) = "Worksheet" Then
        Set r = rangeOrWs.UsedRange
    Else
        MsgBox "Please call with a Range or a Worksheet as argument."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If listDependents Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dependents")
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Precedents")
    End If
    
    ws.Cells(1, 1) = r.Parent.Name
    ws.Cells(2, 1) = r.Address
    ws.Cells(3, 1) = "Cell Address"
    ws.Cells(3, 2) = "Value"
    ws.Cells(3, 3) = "Formula"
    ws.UsedRange.Offset(3, 0).ClearContents
    
    row = 4
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In r.Cells
        Dim deps As Range, depCell As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set deps = Nothing
        Set deps = IIf(listDependents, cell.Dependents, cell.Precedents)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Dim listCurrentCell As Boolean
        
        listCurrentCell = (listOrphans And deps Is Nothing) Or (Not listOrphans And Not deps Is Nothing)
        If listCurrentCell Then
            ws.Cells(row, 1) = cell.Address
            ws.Cells(row, 2) = "'" & cell.Value2
            If Left(cell.Formula2, 1) = "=" Then
                ws.Cells(row, 3) = "'" & cell.Formula2
            End If
        
            If Not listOrphans Then
                col = 4
                For Each depCell In deps
                    If depCell.Parent.Name = cell.Parent.Name Then
                        ws.Cells(row, col) = "'" & depCell.Address
                    Else
                        ws.Cells(row, col) = "'" & depCell.Parent.Name & "!" & depCell.Address
                    End If
                    col = col + 1
                Next
            End If
            row = row + 1
        End If
    Next

    ws.Activate ' Just to show the result.    
End Sub

The code is not optimized for speed and I can imagine that is runs quite a while for very large sheets - play around to figure out what fits best for your needs.
